# NPOI: Iterate all bookmarks of a docx

Tags: c#, .net, apache-poi, npoi

I need your help to find a way to browse all the Bookmarks in a docx with NPOI in C# .NET 4.7.

At the moment I'm doing it this way, but I can't reach the bookmarks that would be in a table for example.

```cs
foreach (XWPFParagraph p in doc.Paragraphs)
{
    foreach (CT_Bookmark b in p.GetCTP().GetBookmarkStartList())
    {
        XWPFRun r = p.CreateRun();
        r.AddPicture(picData, (int)PictureType.PNG, "img", Units.ToEMU(50), Units.ToEMU(50));
    }
}
```

I'd really like to browse all of them, no matter where they are in the document (I need to put an image there).

NPOI is perhaps not the best solution? But it must run without the installation of Office. I am in .NET 4.7 imposed...

Thank you very much in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It’s just that you didn’t find the specific insertion location

```
            foreach (XWPFTable p in doc.Tables)
            {
                foreach (XWPFTableRow b in p.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (XWPFTableCell c in b.GetTableCells())
                    {
                        foreach (var aa in c.Paragraphs)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in aa.GetCTP().GetBookmarkStartList())
                            {
                                if (item.name == "SHR" || item.name == "CHCSR" || item.name == "CHFSR" || item.name == "QDCSR" || item.name == "QDFSR")
                                {
                                    XWPFRun r = aa.CreateRun();
                                    using (FileStream picFile = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\ztgeo\\Desktop\\Snap1.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                                    {
                                        r.AddPicture(picFile, (int)PictureType.PNG, "image", 100 * 12857, 15 * 12857);
                                    }
                                    //r.AddPicture(picData, (int)PictureType.PNG, "img", Units.ToEMU(50), Units.ToEMU(50));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```